# Having trouble dismissing 2 UIActionSheets

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet

I have 2 UIBarButoon in a UIToolbar.  Each has an IBAction to launch their own UIActionSheets.

Right now, if I present one, then click the other UIBarButton, the other ActionSheet gets presented as well, so I have two on the screen and they are overlapping.  I want one to dismiss when the other is presented, etc.

I have this code now:

```
- (IBAction)showFirstActionSheet:(id)sender
{
    if (!self.eRXActionSheet)
    {
        UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"eRX Menu" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"New eRX", @"eRX Refills", nil];
        sheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
        self.eRXActionSheet = sheet;
        [sheet release];

        [self.eRXActionSheet showFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES];

        return;
    }

    [self.eRXActionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:self.eRXActionSheet.cancelButtonIndex animated:YES];
    self.eRXActionSheet = nil;
}

- (IBAction)showSecondActionSheet:(id)sender
{
    if (!self.actionSheet)
    {
        UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Action Menu" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Help", @"Lock", @"Log Out", nil];
        sheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleBlackOpaque;
        self.actionSheet = sheet;
        [sheet release];

        [self.actionSheet showFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES];

        return;
    }

    [self.actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:self.actionSheet.cancelButtonIndex animated:YES];
    self.actionSheet = nil;
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (actionSheet == self.eRXActionSheet)
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            [self erxButtonClicked];
        }
        else if (buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            [self erxRefillButtonClicked];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (buttonIndex == 0)
        {
            [self helpButtonClicked];
        }
        else if (buttonIndex == 1)
        {
            [self lockButtonClicked];
        }
        else if (buttonIndex == 2)
        {
            [self logOut];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, before creating an action sheet, your are checking if the action sheet to be displayed is not nil. Logically, this will always evaluate to true.

Rather you should check if the **other** action sheet is not nil. If so, dismiss it and create the new one.

```
-(void)buttonForActionSheet1Clicked {
    if (actionSheet2 != nil) {
        // dismiss it
    }
    // show actionSheet1
}

-(void)buttonForActionSheet2Clicked {
    if (actionSheet1 != nil) {
        // dismiss it
    }
    // show actionSheet2
}
```

Alternatively, you can force the user to dismiss the present action sheet with the cancel button first by **disabling** the other button in the toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Call `dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:` on the actionsheet you want dismissed.

E.g. in `showFirstActionSheet` add this line to dismiss the other:

```
if(self.actionSheet) [self.actionSheet dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:<indexofCancelButton> animated:YES];
```

Comment: Hey why did you remove your answer on the other question?

Comment: to be honest, I am not sober enough to understand exactly what you wanted:(

Comment: Can i make the question more clear and you can provide an answer?

Comment: I'm off to sleep now. About that other question: I suggest using a singleton object to retain a pointer to the UIActionsheet, that way you can access it from anywhere in the app and dismiss it, it is a bit of a cheat though (and not very elegant).